# Jquery Sliding Tabs- how can disable top menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am trying to disable the top menu for **jquery sliding tabs**. I want the tabs to tabs to be operated only with previous/next.

Please see my [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/4/).

Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Horizontal Sliding Tabs demo
    $('div#st_horizontal').slideTabs({
        // Options              
        contentAnim: 'slideH',
        contentAnimTime: 600,
        contentEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        tabsAnimTime: 300
    });

    $(".st_tab_view").each(function(i) {
        var totalSize = $(".st_tab_view").size() - 1;
        if (i != totalSize) {
            next = i + 2;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next Page &#187;</a>");
        }
        if (i !== 0) {
            prev = i;
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>&#171; Prev Page</a>");
        }
    });

    $('.prev-tab').click(function() {
        $('.st_tab_active').parent().prev().children('a').trigger('click');
        return false;
    });

    $('.next-tab').click(function() {
        $('.st_tab_active').parent().next().children('a').trigger('click');
        return false;
    });


});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"

Horizontal Tab #1

modify your jquery like -

$('.prev-tab').click(function() {
         $('.st_tab_active').attr('disabled','disabled');
        var tab= $('.st_tab_active').parent().prev().children('a');
        tab.removeAttr('disabled');
        tab.trigger('click');
       // tab.attr('disabled','disabled');
        return false;
    });

```
$('.next-tab').click(function() {
    $('.st_tab_active').attr('disabled','disabled');
   var tab=  $('.st_tab_active').parent().next().children('a');
    tab.removeAttr('disabled');
    tab.trigger('click');
    //tab.attr('disabled','disabled');
    return false;
});
```

"

Comment: +1 for your answer. This is how i wanted to go as of disabling the top menu. But in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/65/) this method is not working. Take a look [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/65/)

Comment: add disabled attribute for each href like
"<li><a href="#st_content_1" rel="tab_1" class="st_tab st_first_tab st_tab_active" disabled>Horizontal Tab #1</a></li>
"

Comment: I have modified the jQuery to show selected tab, see the modified answer. Try this ...

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But with the modification it is not working. the top menu is still clickable. I want the top menu to show but not to be clickable. Take a look at the modifactions you provide me: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PS336/87/).

Comment: i tried your link and it is working fine. I am using IE-8, which browser your are working on?

Comment: are you talking about the slider tab which are at the extreme right and left side of the screen or about the "Horizontal Tab#', which one is clickable?

Comment: No, i am talking about what is in the middle of the slider tab. For example "Horizontal Tab #1, Horizontal Tab #2, Horizontal Tab #3 ,etc" I want to disable those links from the user. I only want them to use Previous and next. I am sorry if I sound confusing.

Comment: in your given link, it is working exactly what you want. please try in IE 8 or tell me the browser you are using

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13014/discussion-between-jonthecoder2346-and-bhushan-kawadkar)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following CSS:

```
div.st_horizontal div.st_tabs_container { /* Tabs main container */        
    position:relative;
    /* This will hide it all together */
    display:none;
    z-index:100;    
    /* Or change with and heights */    
    width:0% !important;    
    height:0px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;    
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or, you could add more CSS on your page (after where the jQuery UI CSS is added), to save overwriting default CSS:

```
div.st_horizontal div.st_tabs_container {
    /* This will hide it all together */
    display:none;
    /* Or change with and heights */    
    width:0% !important;    
    height:0px;
}
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend writing your own control.

Either of these two saves diving into jQuery code!

Comment: +1, I like your method. Is there a way to show the selected tab but keep the others hidden.

Comment: div.st_horizontal ul.st_tabs li a {
    display:none;
}

div.st_horizontal ul.st_tabs li a.st_tab_active {
    display:block;
}

Add as many other exceptions to the bottom one (e.g. for next/prev buttons)